# Handle Exceptions when using @RequestHeader in spring application

Tags: java, spring, web-services, exception

Here is my Java code that uses the Spring Framework:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String SampleFunction(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String details)
{
    System.out.println("Authorization details recieved");

}
```

I am trying to access `Authorization` header.  I want to handle the missing `Authorization` header by redirecting it to a 400 Bad Request page. How can I do this?

Comment: Show what you have tried already.

Comment: Please add additional detail to your question including the programming language.

Comment: I tried to make sense of this question, please let me know if I failed to improve clarity.

Answer (score 14):

By default the header is required. So if it is missing, you will get an exception.
However, see code below. Now, if it is missing, the details string will be null.

```
@RequestHeader(required = false, value = "Authorization") String details
```

Comment: how can i do this `required = false` as the default behavior? Or i need to do it in every `@RequestHeader` in my app?

Answer (score 0):

If the header value is missing by default the response is  400 Bad Request. You just need to configure redirecting.