# Use @RequestHeader("Authorization") parameter but not use it in the method body?

Tags: java, spring

The annotation [@RequestHeader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) of Spring framework indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request header.

I work in a project where the `@RequestHeader` parameter is used in many request but the parameter itself is never used in the method body.

Exemple:

```
@Secure(requiresToken = TokenType.USER)
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello.htm")
public String hello(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String accessToken) {
    return "hello";
}
```

Is it really necessary to have the parameter `accessToken` if it is not used in the method body ?

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601150/handle-exceptions-when-using-requestheader-in-spring-application

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory to use the `@RequestHeader` annotation on top of your handler function.  However, if used, the corresponding values can be used within the function.  "User Agent", "Accept Language", "Cookie" are some of the values that can be accessed with the `@RequestHeader` annotation.

If you are not using the value within the function, having that annotation is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I understood, this parameter was replaced by an interceptor based on [AsyncHandlerInterceptor](http://HandlerInterceptorAdapter) and implemented with a custom annotation `@Secure(requiresToken = TokenType.USER)`.

By this way, it is not necessary to pass the `@RequestHeader` parameter.

We continue to pass this parameter to allow [swagger](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/) the description of the mandatory element `tokenAcces`on all the requests.

Ex:[image]